# Set the initial selected option for rendered select in DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a problem to append a selected value option in a DataTable.

Here is my JavaScript code

```
  var table = $('#tablesurvey').DataTable( {
    "ajax": {
        "url": '<?php echo site_url('data'); ?>',
        "type": "POST"
    },

    "columns": [
        {"data": "id_vote"},
        {"data": "nama"},
        {"data": "nik"},
        {"data": "desa"},
        {"data": "rt"},
        {"data": "vote"}
    ],
        "columnDefs": [ {
            "targets": -1,
            "render": function (data, type, row, meta){
             return "<select class='pilihan form-control' id='pilihan'><option value='0'>--Pilihan--</option><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option</select>";
         }
        } ],
    } );
```

> Result before

[image: 1]]

> Result what I want

[image: 2]]

How do I set the initial selected option for the rendered select box?

Comment: What do you mean by "*append selected value option in DataTable*" ...?

Comment: Example : {"data": "vote"} is number  "1" , I want to set select option selected in "1"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could build the `<select>` programmatically, i.e step by step adding `<option>`'s and compare with `data.vote`. Or you could use a more generic jQuery based solution for convenience :

```
render: function (data, type, row, meta){
  var $select = $("<select class='pilihan form-control' id='pilihan'><option value='0'>--Pilihan--</option><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option></select>");
  $select.find('option[value="'+data.vote+'"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
  return $select[0].outerHTML
}
```

Comment: Working PERFECT, I change **data.vote** to **data** , thank you @davidkonrad