# Datatables - Set dropdown on response from AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have a table that with the following columns:

UUID - Title - Location - Set State

The JSON I return from the server looks like:

```
{"uuid": 2, "title": "Some title", "location": "California", "state": "CLOSED"}
```

There are 3 different states that I can return from the server, and those are:

1. Open
2. Pending
3. Closed

I am trying to understand how it would be possible for me to dynamically set the 'State' of a row item (i.e. 'selected' in the dropdown) and populate the dropdown with the other two option (not selected).

EDIT: Here is my example HTML (notice that my javascript currently just renders a dropdown, not based on the data returned):

```
<table id="table" class="display">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>UUID</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Set State</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    </table>
```

And Javascript

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/some/endpoint/
    cache: false,
    success: function(response){
        var table = $('#table').DataTable({
            "sAjaxSource": "/some/endpoint/",
            "orderClasses": false,
            "order": [[ 3, "asc" ]],
            "aoColumns": [
                { "mData": "uuid" },
                { "mData": "title" },
                { "mData": "location" },
                {
                    mData: "Set State",
                    bSortable: false,
                    mRender: function (data, type, row) {
                        return '<select>' +
                            '<option value="active">ACTIVE</option>' +
                            '<option value="pending">PENDING</option>' +
                            '<option value="closed">CLOSED</option>' +
                            '</select>'
                    }
                }
            ],
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is it for DataTables rendering or a general question?

Comment: This is for DataTables. I've updated my question. Thanks!

Comment: Then there is multiple duplicates, latest I know of is this -> https://stackoverflow.com/q/47110600/1407478 (my own answer, but this or a variant of this is the way to go)

Comment: Thats exactly what I needed @davidkonrad. Thanks for the help. I will update my answer with link.

Answer (score 0):

If your response is an array of objects. This is what you need to do.

```js
var array = [{ "uuid": 2, "title": "Some title", "location": "California", "state": "OPEN" }, { "uuid": 3, "title": "Other title", "location": "New york", "state": "PENDING" }];
var options = ["OPEN", "CLOSED", "PENDING"];


for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
var selectList = document.createElement("select");
    myDiv.appendChild(selectList);
    selectList.setAttribute("id", array[i].uuid);
    for(var j =0; j<options.length; j++){
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.setAttribute("value", options[j]);
    option.text = options[j];
    selectList.appendChild(option);
    }
    selectList.value = array[i].state
   
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

I am assuming you've already created a `dropdown` in your html. Now when you get response from server you can set the selected value of your dropdown to the state of what you received in response by something like
    `document.getElementById('idOfYourSelect').value = response.status`

Here is `snippet` for demo:

```js
var response = {
  "uuid": 2,
  "title": "Some title",
  "location": "California",
  "state": "OPEN"
};

function setSelectedValue(response) {
  document.getElementById('status').value = response.state.toUpperCase();
}
setSelectedValue(response);
```

```html
<select id="status">
    <option value="CLOSED">Closed</option>
    <option value="OPEN">Open</option>
    <option value="PENDING">Pending</option>
</select>
```

Comment: May have to accommodate case-sensitive option values, but it looks like this would work.

Comment: @codemaker yeah thanks for your suggestion. I've handled that in edit :)

Comment: @UsmanRana - So because I am using datatables, I populate the table dynamically. I've updated my original question with my HTML and javascript. Are you suggesting I do a second AJAX call to same endpoint to update the dropdown?

Comment: No. just assign an `id` to your dynamically created `dropdown` and call the function `setSelectedValue` and pass response to this function. That should work

Comment: What if the response is an array of objects such as: 

[{
  "uuid": 2,
  "title": "Some title",
  "location": "California",
  "state": "OPEN"
}, {
  "uuid": 3,
  "title": "Other title",
  "location": "New york",
  "state": "CLOSED"
}]

I guess I can try appending the UUID to the ID of the dropdown as you have suggested and implement the logic to update the state based on the row that is being iterated over. I had hoped there might be a cleaner solution. Regardless, thanks for your help!

Comment: @Bryce. Please check the updated answer. will be helpful